# How to separate display of decimals from a float number in Jinja?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using Jinja like `{{{:.2f}".format(price)|}}`
But I want to separately display integer part and decimals.

For Integer I have `price|int`. How can I use format to only display decimals, but no integer part?

Because I want to put them in separate places. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can split formatted price by `.`

```
template = """
  {% set int_part, decimal_part = "{:.2f}".format(price).split('.') %}
  int_part: {{ int_part }}
  decimal_part: {{ decimal_part }}
"""

Environment().from_string(template).render(price=1.4567)
>>   int_part: 1
     decimal_part: 46
```